# css width and height doesn't work

Tags: html, css

I have the following code, but width/height of spans doesn't really work.

HTML

```
<div id="amount" class="ch_field3">
<span id="ch_minus">-</span> 3 <span id="ch_plus">+</span>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.shop_chekout_item{min-width: 100%; float: left;}
.shop_chekout_item .ch_field3{display: block;float: left; width: 20%;}

.shop_chekout_item #ch_plus,.shop_chekout_item #ch_minus{
background: #ccc; 
width:  20px; /*no effect...*/
height: 20px; /*same here :(*/
cursor: pointer}
```

Answer (score 13):

Spans are `display: inline;` by default.

To get them to listen to a height and width, you'll need to add `display: block;`.

Comment: Which makes spans act like divs, so to reduce confusion, use dive instead.

Answer (score 1):

Because the CSS selectors are namespaced with `.shop_chekout_item`, a wrapping div needs to be added around the HTML code. Then it will work. [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/briankueck/p9b15m7s/)

HTML:

```
<div class="shop_chekout_item">
  <div id="amount" class="ch_field3">
    <span id="ch_minus">-</span> 3 <span id="ch_plus">+</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Tips:

1. Use `display: inline-block;` to avoid having to `float:left;`
2. Use `text-align: center;` & `vertical-align: middle;` to make it look nice. :)

CSS:

```
.shop_chekout_item{min-width: 100%; float: left;}
.shop_chekout_item .ch_field3{display: block;float: left; width: 20%;}

.shop_chekout_item #ch_plus,
.shop_chekout_item #ch_minus{
  background: #ccc; 
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width:  20px;
  height: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a property `display: block;` right before the width and height setting. Should work now, as by default the spans are `display: inline;`

Answer (score 0):

While the display property is `inline`, **height** and **width** will not work.

```
display :inline;
```

By changing the display property from `inline` to `block` or `inline-block`, height and width should be worked properly.

```
display: block ;
// or
display: inline-block
```

Answer (score 0):

The default  `display` property of **span** is `inline`, so **width** and **height** properties will be not considered.

Instead use

```
display: inline-block;
```

//or

```
display: block;
```

here `display:block;` will span the element's width.